# Shortcut to put the selected region in an ordinary LaTeX environment (not with begin-end style) using auctex

Tags: key-bindings, latex, auctex, region

In auctex if one has a selected region and then apply the command `c-c c-e` (LaTeX-environment) then by selecting an environment, the selected region will be folded between that environment.

Is there a similar command to put a selected region between an ordinary command (not begin-end environments, but ordinary latex environment)?

As a specific example assume that one would like to put the selected region between the braces in `\underline{}`. Is there a command which takes the name of the environment (in this case `unerline`) then put the selected region between the braces in `\underline{}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for `C-c RET` which invokes `TeX-insert-macro`.

Answer (score 1):

AUCTeX provides [Font-Specifiers](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Font-Specifiers.html#Font-Specifiers) that one can use for such environments as described in the question and which are used often. For instance the following code

```
(add-to-list 'LaTeX-font-list
  '(?\C-q "\\underline{" "}"))
```

will add `underline` to the list of font specifiers. This code must be called after `LaTeX-font-list` is defined. Then when you press `C-c C-f C-q` without selected region `\underline{}` will be created and the cursor is put between the braces. If you have a marked `region` then the result will be  `\underline{region}`